# automatically include subfolder of org files?

Tags: org-mode

My team is using a big single `org-mode` file to manage our research notes but some people are complaining that the file is getting too big too manage and the git conflicts are becoming a pain.

The [docs say to use links](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#how-to-organize-org-mode-files) to manage multiple `.org` files, like a wiki, but that also suffers from the git conflict problem (now when two people add a file, their link suffers the conflict) plus it's a massive pain to maintain the links.

Is there a way to automatically include a subfolder of `.org` files in a main file, or (as a fallback) automatically generate the table of files to include? Order is not important but I suppose lexicographic ordering of the filenames would be useful.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to compile out the entire document to one readable HTML page so links out to separate documents is very much sub-optimal.

Comment: In which order should the files be included? An automated solution won't let you have control over that. Are you really going from a one file situation to a hundreds of files situation at once?

Comment: Org Babel blocks can output Org code. So you can use an `ls` or `find` or `dir` command to generate `#+INCLUDE` statements for a folder hierarchy.

Comment: oooh that sounds interesting @mankoff could you please expand on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Babel can generate Org code. Try evaluating a Babel block on export that generates the `+#INCLUDE:` statements for you.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results raw drawer
for f in $(find /path/to/files/ -name "*.org"); do
    echo "#+INCLUDE: " $f
done
#+END_SRC
```

Generates:

```
#+RESULTS:
:RESULTS:
#+INCLUDE:  /path/to/files/A.org
#+INCLUDE:  /path/to/files/Bsubdir/foo.org
#+INCLUDE:  /path/to/files/C.org
:END:
```

Comment: oh wow, simple and powerful, I like it! Just need to rerun this every couple of weeks to ensure everything is in sync.

Comment: Using `:results drawer replace`, the export engine will handle the INCLUDE keywords appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like [including other files](http://orgmode.org/manual/Include-files.html) could be what you want. It is a way to include other files in an org-file (could be other org-files or other file types), but when exporting it will all be exported as a single document.

Comment: cool, but it doesn't include folders of org files, right? Let's say I have 100 files across two folders and I don't want to have to manually manage that.

Comment: No, I do not think it works on folders. In what order would those 100 files appear in the document, in that case? Perhaps the publishing functionality could be used for this case: http://orgmode.org/manual/Publishing.html